# GLX missing, segmentation fault

Tags: wireless

I have installed all the individual components of SIDsuite.
Next,the command that is used to start the monitoring application is called sidstart. I have placed $HOME/bin directory into command search path, and now we can start up the monitoring application by simply typing sidstart at the command prompt.But i am getting an error when i type sidstart:

Using Volk machine: sse4_2_32
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Segmentation fault

Answer (score 1):

Your software is complaining that it cannot find support for OpenGL.

This is most likely due to the fact that the drivers you are using don't have support for 3D. If your graphic card is Nvidia or ATI make sure that the drivers installed are the proper ones

For [Nvidia](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia).
For [ATI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI)